# Merge substring in a column based on duplicates in another column

Tags: r

For all the values in `geneNames` columns that are duplicated, merge the values in the corresponding `probeID` column and collapse with ";". Keep only the one copy if geneNames` columns have duplicated values.

Attempt:

```
meth.anno.2 <- paste(meth.anno.2$probeID,";")[duplicated(meth.anno.2$geneNames)]
```

Input

```
   > dput(meth.anno.2[1:10,])
    structure(list(probeID = c("cg13869341", "cg14008030", "cg12045430", 
    "cg20826792", "cg00381604", "cg20253340", "cg21870274", "cg03130891", 
    "cg24335620", "cg16162899"), geneNames = c("WASH7P", "MIR6859-1", 
    "MIR1302-2", "MIR1302-2", "MIR1302-2", "OR4F5", "OR4F5", "AL627309", 
    "AL627309", "AL732372")), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Expected output

```
structure(list(probeID = c("cg13869341", "cg14008030", "cg12045430;cg20826792;cg00381604", 
"cg20253340;cg21870274", "cg03130891;cg24335620", "cg24335620", 
"cg16162899"), geneNames = c("WASH7P", "MIR6859-1", "MIR1302-2", 
"OR4F5", "OR4F5", "AL627309", "AL732372")), row.names = c(NA, 
7L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

Aggregate in Base R should solve your problem:

```
aggregate(probeID~geneNames, meth.anno.2, paste, collapse= ';')

  geneNames                          probeID
1  AL627309            cg03130891;cg24335620
2  AL732372                       cg16162899
3 MIR1302-2 cg12045430;cg20826792;cg00381604
4 MIR6859-1                       cg14008030
5     OR4F5            cg20253340;cg21870274
6    WASH7P                       cg13869341
```

Answer (score 0):

**With Dplyr**

We need to group by (`.by`) geneNames, then `paste` the probeID values with the `;` separator.

```
library(dplyr)
meth.anno.2 |> 
     summarise(probeID = paste(probeID, collapse = ";"),
               .by = geneNames)

1                       cg13869341    WASH7P
2                       cg14008030 MIR6859-1
3 cg12045430;cg20826792;cg00381604 MIR1302-2
4            cg20253340;cg21870274     OR4F5
5            cg03130891;cg24335620  AL627309
6                       cg16162899  AL732372
```

If we really need the order of variables specified in the output above, simply pipe the output into `relocate`, as in:

```
df |> 
     summarise(probeID = paste(probeID, collapse = ";"),
               .by = geneNames)|>
     relocate(geneNames, .after = probeID)

                           probeID geneNames
1                       cg13869341    WASH7P
2                       cg14008030 MIR6859-1
3 cg12045430;cg20826792;cg00381604 MIR1302-2
4            cg20253340;cg21870274     OR4F5
5            cg03130891;cg24335620  AL627309
6                       cg16162899  AL732372
```

But this method (storing several values pasted into long character scalars) makes the data difficult to work on in downstream analyses.
To make your life easier, consider some "tidy" methods, such as `nest`ing the data.frames or using `list`-columns:

```
### with list-columns:

df |> 
    summarise(probeID = list(probeID),
              .by = geneNames)

  geneNames                            probeID
1    WASH7P                         cg13869341
2 MIR6859-1                         cg14008030
3 MIR1302-2 cg12045430, cg20826792, cg00381604
4     OR4F5             cg20253340, cg21870274
5  AL627309             cg03130891, cg24335620
6  AL732372                         cg16162899

## with nest()

library(tidyr)

df |> 
    nest(.by = geneNames, .key = "probeID")

# A tibble: 6 × 2
  geneNames probeID         
  <chr>     <list>          
1 WASH7P    <tibble [1 × 1]>
2 MIR6859-1 <tibble [1 × 1]>
3 MIR1302-2 <tibble [3 × 1]>
4 OR4F5     <tibble [2 × 1]>
5 AL627309  <tibble [2 × 1]>
6 AL732372  <tibble [1 × 1]>
```

If we then want to use the `probeID` column, it gets much easier.
See what we get if we extract the probeID after the list-column approach, which gets us a list of vectors.:

```
[[1]]
[1] "cg13869341"

[[2]]
[1] "cg14008030"

[[3]]
[1] "cg12045430" "cg20826792" "cg00381604"

[[4]]
[1] "cg20253340" "cg21870274"

[[5]]
[1] "cg03130891" "cg24335620"

[[6]]
[1] "cg16162899"
```

Comment: I hade missread the separator required. Corrected the answer now